# How to find the ID in database in OnClick?

Tags: android

I'm using listView and in every line I have a button. I'm using OnClick and not a listener. 
When I press the button I need to update the database. How can I know what is the ID?
here is my code:

```
public void saleButtonClick(View v) {
            int quantity = 0;
            TextView mQuantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_quantity);
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(mQuantityTextView.getText().toString());

            if (quantity > 0){
                quantity --;
                Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(BookEntry.CONTENT_URI,  v.getId());
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(BookEntry.COLUMN_BOOK_QUANTITY, quantity);
                int rowsUpdated = getContentResolver().update(
                        updateUri,
                        values,
                        null,
                        null);
                if (rowsUpdated == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.sellable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_sellable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } else {
                //  Out of stock
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.out_of_stock, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mQuantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(quantity));
    }
```

Comment: Which ID are you talking about ?

Comment: Please add a code example to the question.

Comment: ID in the databse. I want to update the row in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ListView with CursorAdapter (+ContentProvider) then you should add onClickListener in your CursorAdapter. In this case all of your List Items will have the SaleButton connected to your product (with it's unique id).
Try this code in your Adapter:

```
Button saleButton = view.findViewById(R.id.sale_button);
    saleButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        sellItem(_id, productQuantity);
    });

 /**
 * helper method for sell a product
 * @param id - id of product
 * @param productQuantity - original quantity which must decreased by one
 */
private void sellItem(long id, int productQuantity) {
   int newQuantity = --productQuantity;

    // check that new quantity is greater than 0. In this case we update product
    if (newQuantity > 0) {
        ContentValues sellItem = new ContentValues();
        sellItem.put(BookEntry.COLUMN_BOOK_QUANTITY, quantity);
        int result= mContext.getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(BookEntry.CONTENT_URI,id),sellItem,null,null);
        if(result==1){
            // rest of your code
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.
I had a very similar project, take a look at: https://github.com/csongi77/InventoryApp
Best regards!

Comment: in the bind method?

Comment: Yes, in bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) method. Therefore you can extract _id from Cursor. If it helps, please don't forget to accept my answer. Thanks in advance!  :)

Comment: I used instead:         saleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              sellItem(_id, quantity);
           }
      });